# values.xml when uncompiling APK

Tags: android, proguard

I'm using Proguard and realm as db, and I need to use a protected API Key to connect my webservices.

I'm decompiling my apk, and can't see values.xml

Is it absolutely sure to store Api keys and other importants stuff in values.xml???

I was thinking in storing my Key in serverside, in DB, but then, query would be open, without API Key ( as I want to get it ), so you can easily uncompile android code, get url, and get API Key.

What's the best way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

When compiling an apk, you should have a folder called values. Inside that folder, you will find all your values defined like strings.xml, dimens.xml, styles.xml, etc...

So that won't be very safe. It's always better to write your api key as a static method in code. Nothing will be able to decompile your code, especially when using Proguard.